# Is this list syntax correct?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, lists

I saw the following sentence earlier:

> We’ll help you win across every channel, every format and on your terms.

I interpret that as one of the following:

- We’ll help you win; [across every channel], [every format], [on your terms].

  - But "help you win...every format" doesn't seem intentional, even if it is grammatically correct.
- We’ll help you win across; [every channel], [every format], [on your terms].

  - But "help you win across...on your terms" is not correct.

I feel like the sentence should repeat "across" like it repeats "every":

> We’ll help you win across every channel, **across** every format and on your terms.

- Is my version more correct? Is it better, or am I trying to be too logical?
- Is there a term for a list where a preceding word applies to more than one item but not all items?

Comment: Your version works. I'd use: We’ll help you win across every channel *and format. and do it on* your own terms.

Comment: According to many, though, you oughta have a comma after _format_. They'd think it was uneducated. Opinions differ.

Answer (score 1):

*Is there a term for a list where a preceding word applies to more than one item but not all items?*

It’s an example of non-parallel sentence structure.

Your quotation is apparently from a company called Magnite, which seems to be a real company.

The use of grammatical error in advertising is a means of getting and keeping attention:

> ”Everybody doesn’t like something, but nobody doesn’t like Sara Lee.”

> ”Think different.”

Don’t they know? Of course they know.